# Facebook key Hash does not match any stored key hash

Tags: android, facebook

I have been trying to implement facebook share from my android application. I have gone through this documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share.

I have successfully integrated my development key hashes for once and successfully shared to facebook from my application. The problem is when I am trying to implement the same steps for my another application. I have successfully added my key hashes and linked up my application with facebook but when I hit "POST", it is showing that Key hashes does not match and the key hash that is coming with the error message is showing the previous application's key hash.

I have double checked my key hash using this.

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "My Project", 
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        Toast.makeText(this, Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: I have figured out one thing, which is the hash key which I have found from using the code above is not working when inserting it to facebook development key hashes , but when inserting the previous application's hash key it is working. Isn't it supposed to be different for different applications?

Comment: It may be the same if you use it with the same Keystore you publish both your app. Especially if you are using the Debug Keystore of Eclipse or something like that. Try and read how to get your Debug and Release Key Hashes for Facbook in Android, you have plenty of examples online.

Comment: Well, I have followed examples from online and successfully made one application running. I use the same keystore , that is true indeed but while running the code above why it is showing a different key hash then? That is what making me confused.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have 2 Key hashes.
One for Debugging and the second is for release, when you publish your application to Google Play using a custom-made keystore instead of the Android Debug one.

Your scenario sounds like your are running your application from Eclipse/Android Studio and when you do that you are using the Debug keystore key hash which you have probably included in Facebook Developer Console already like in your previous app.

If you are exporting your APK with a different keystore you will have to get its Hash Key for this specific key store, like in the online examples you mentioned above.

I will be happy to know if you are signing your APK with debug keystore or your own. That will make things more simpler to answer.